# Printing a sequence in R using paste

Tags: r, newline, paste

I wish to print like this:

```
Hello 2015
Hello 2016
Hello 2017
Hello 2018
```

I wrote this code

```
vecn=15:18
cat("\n",paste0(" Hello 20",vecn),"\n")
```

It is not giving me the desired output. They are getting printed in one line, I want them in a new line every time. Please help.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
vecn=15:18

cat(paste0(" Hello 20",vecn,"\n" ))
```